# Doing overloading through a generic method

Tags: java, generics

My motivation is to create a set of overloaded functions called toString(), which takes any object (or at least those I'm interested in) and creates a string usefull for debugging. Then I also like to have an out() method, without have to recreate the same (tedious) overloading.

I see that what I get with this code is that toString(e) in out() always calls toString(Object). I can't see a way around this after looking into generics. So if anyone has the insight into how this could be done, I would appreciate it.

To sum up :

- Is there a elegant way to implement the out() method, taking advantage of the exiting overloading of toString().
- Can this be done with generics?

  ```
  public class A3 {

      static <E> void out(E e){
          System.out.println(toString(e));
      }

      static String toString(Object o){
          return "Object";
      }

      static String toString(String str){
          return "String";
      }

      static String toString(Integer i){
          return "Integer";
      }

      static String toString(SomeObject o){
          return "A description of the object";
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          out("");
          out(1);
      }

  }
  ```

EDIT: Extended example to clarify meaning.

Comment: Why don't you just `@Override Object#toString` in you objects and get rid of this Rube Goldberg thing?

Comment: This Rube Goldberg thing is for creating a toString() for mig purpose only :-) I might not be able to change the classes that I want to format. And the toString() of most built-in objects don't give convenient information.

Comment: Got it. Although you could always extend or anonymize the classes you can't modify directly, and add your formatting functionality (if they're not final, that is). Looking at your design, you're entering a world of pain - fair warning :)

Comment: @mene I agree about the world of pain :-)

Comment: the "double dispatch" problem :)

Comment: I think I would call it "deferred dispatch" :-) Doesn't double dispatch mean dispatch based on two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to achieve this using reflection (if you are ok to use it),

```
Method method = A3.class.getDeclaredMethod("toString", e.getClass());
System.out.println(method.invoke(null, e));
```

This will invoke the `toString()` method based on the class of `e` argument.

Comment: What if `e.getClass()` is a subtype of one of the types in the signature ?

Comment: This is very promissing. It seems to work exactly how I want. And the issue of subtype: The call to `getDeclaredMethod` will throw an exception, if the exact signature don't exist in the class. Even if there exists a method, that takes the parent type. That works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Which method is called is determined at compile time.  If you want dynamic checks you have to code this yourself.

The only way is to use a string of `if` and `instanceof` checks.

```
static <E> void out(E e){
    Object o = e instanceof String ? toString((String) e) :
               e instanceof Integer ? toString((Integer) e) :
               toString(e);
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Or a better option would be to implement

```
static String toString(Object o) {
    return o instanceof String ? "String" :
           o instanceof Integer ? "Integer" :
               "Object";
}
```

Note: Unless you do this `toString((Object) "hello")` will return "Object"

Comment: Even better than testing and avoiding coding tests (because I suppose the list can grow) `toString`: `toString(Object o) { return o == null ? "<null>" : o.getClass().getSimpleName(); }`

Comment: @Peter I see your point. But it seems like the same trouble you get creating overloading of out().

Comment: Your suggesting of `toString` is the best solution (when not using overloading) which I would prefer. The the `out` method would be straight forward. What I hoped to see, was a solution where `out` could be implemented without touching the `toString` methods.

Comment: @wistoft it can but the toString is flawed in the sense that the type isn't check dynamically (see my last line)

Comment: You are right about that. It could be a source of confusion, if I don't know the exact type, the overloaded `toString` could give a misleading answer. This is very good argument for doing your `toString` suggestion and avoid static overloading.

Answer (score 3):

There may be various ways to achieve what you *actually* want to achieve. And there may be various ways to achieve what you want to achieve, based on the code and constraints that you mentioned. But focussing on this point:

> Is there a elegant way to implement the out() method, taking advantage of the exiting overloading of toString().

In order to take advantage of these methods, you have to dispatch to the desired method. The method must either be known at compile time, or determined from the type of the given object at runtime. However, this can not be done based on generics and the language-internal [method overload resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), because the generic parameters are bascially replaced with `Object` during the compilation.

One way to solve this would be to register `Function`s for the desired `toString` method in a common map, and looking up these functions at runtime.

Note that this is not necessarily a "good" solution for what you actually want to do, but shows one way of "*taking advantage of the existing overloadings*" in a generic and easily extensible way.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class GenericToString
{
    private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<?, String>> 
        TO_STRING_FUNCTIONS = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static <C> void register(Class<C> c, Function<C, String> f)
    {
        TO_STRING_FUNCTIONS.put(c, f);
    }
    static
    {
        register(Object.class, x -> toString(x));
        register(String.class, x -> toString(x));
        register(Integer.class, x -> toString(x));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        out("x");
        out(1);
        out(1.0);
    }

    static void out(Object object)
    {
        System.out.println(toStringDispatcher(object));
    }

    static String toString(Object o)
    {
        return "Object: "+o;
    } 

    static String toString(String s)
    {
        return "String: "+s;
    }

    static String toString(Integer i)
    {
        return "Integer: "+i;
    }    

    private static String toStringDispatcher(Object object)
    {
        if (object == null)
        {
            return "null";
        }
        Function<?, String> f = TO_STRING_FUNCTIONS.get(object.getClass());
        if (f != null)
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Function<Object, String> g = (Function<Object, String>)f;
            return g.apply(object);
        }
        return toString(object);
    }

}
```

Comment: I like the effort you've into. I haven't thought of doing it this way. However I think CodeBender provided a simple solution, that essentially does the same. There the lookup is done using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the class in the code and return it.

```
static <E> void out(E e){
    System.out.println(toString(e));
}

static String toString(Object o){
    return o.getClass().getName();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    out("");
    out(1);
}
```

Comment: Or `getSimpleName()` instead of `getName()`;

Comment: You are right for the first example I provided. I've expanded the example to motivate the reason I seek a more complicated solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Test
{

    static void out(Handler<?> h)
    {
        System.out.println(h.ref.getClass());
    }

    private static final class Handler<T>
    {

        final T ref;

        Handler(T ref)
        {
            this.ref = ref;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        out(new Handler<>("1"));
        out(new Handler<>(new Integer(1)));
        out(new Handler<>(new Double(1)));
        out(new Handler<>(new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Socket>>()));
    }
}
```

Result

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Double
class java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: What is this supposed to have achieved ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to do, but this display the type of the object that come into the method "out", whatever this object is.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I think the strings he chose are mere examples, not what he actually wants to do, he just wants a string based on the type but not necessarily the name of the type. This is a genericity issue not just printing `Object.getClass`.